# half equations for a lead-acid cell

Tags: electrochemistry

we are learning about galvanic cells. I would like to know the half equations and overall equation that occurs in this lead acid cell. so far my understanding for the oxidisation section is that in a lead acid battery oxidisation occurs in lead which has the equation Pb →Pb2+. The equation for the overall reaction at the anode is Pb + SO42- → PbSO4 + 2e-. is this correct because i am confused about the sulphuric acid as i thought it was H2SO4 but a lot of sites have it as SO4 or HSO4.

Comment: See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/89562/9757

Comment: Remember that both $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ and $\ce{HSO4^{-}}$ are from $\ce{H2SO4}$